# SharePoint: Move files from one document library to another using Web Services

Tags: c#, web-services, sharepoint-2010

The requirment is that the Windows Form Application could access the Lists list so the user can choose the Source List and the Destination List.

I am having a problem accessing the **Lists** from the site collection. I access the **XML** of the site by **_vti_bin/ListData.svc**, here i can get the items of the **SPECIFIC LIST**.

How do access the Lists list and move the Files?

Here are my codes:

```
private void setContents(string strSource, string strDestination, string strUser,
        string strPW, string strDomain)
    {
        sourceContent = new SourceSiteDataContext(
        new Uri(strSource));
        destinationContent = new DestinationSiteDataContext(
        new Uri(strDestination));

        userContext = new NetworkCredential();

        userContext.UserName = strUser;
        userContext.Password = strPW;
        userContext.Domain = strDomain;
        sourceContent.Credentials = userContext;
        destinationContent.Credentials = userContext;
    }

ArrayList list = new ArrayList();           
        var sourceQuery = from sourceList in sourceContent.SourceLibrary
                          select new
                          {
                              sourceList.Name
                          };
        foreach (var item in sourceQuery)
        {
            list.Add(item.Name);
        }

private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        setContents("http://[site]:[port]/_vti_bin/ListData.svc",
            "http://[site]:[port]//sites/DestinationSite/_vti_bin/ListData.svc",
            "admin", "admin", "localhost");
        setDropDown();

    }
```

the Code here can only take items from a specific list in the code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The list services are for pulling information only. To perform changes you will need to use the Sharepoint client object model.

Check MSDN http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee857094%28office.14%29.aspx